# How to find exact substring inside a string using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

```
var str = "Hello World +1 new test Good Morning";
var subStr = "+1 new test";
```

I want the code snippet to return true only when entire phrase i.e. "+1 new test" is found in the string str. I have tried regEx and match,search,test options. But, none are working for me. It shows error for the '+'.

Below is what I am using -

```
    var HVal = "Hello World +1 Good"
    var HValNew = HVal.toString().toUpperCase();
    var probStr = "Hello World";
    var test = probStr.toUpperCase();  
    var re = new RegExp('\\b'+test+'\\b'); 
    re.test(HValNew);
```

This works when probStr is a string containing alphanumeric characters but fails when it has special characters e.g. "+", "?"

I found my answer to match exact phrase

```
        var str = "Hello World +1 new test Good Morning".toString().toUpperCase();
        var subStr = "+1 new test".toString().toUpperCase(); 
        escapeSpecialChars = function(string) {return string.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, 'x')};
        var probStr = escapeSpecialChars(subStr);
        var strNew = escapeSpecialChars(str);
        var re = new RegExp("\\b"+probStr+"\\b"); 
        re.test(strNew);
```

This return true when subStr = "+1 new test" and false when subStr = ""+1 new te" (i.e. in case of partial phrase).

Comment: `str.indexOf(subStr) > -1`

Comment: `+` has a special meaning in regexp you need to escape that using `\+`

Comment: I'd suggest just taking a glance at the documentation for [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String), and learning those methods, which will help you solve this problem and many more that you will encounter in the future.

Comment: IndexOf is giving result as true for partial substring too

Answer (score 1):

Use [**includes()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) function in **ES6**, and [**indexOf()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) in **ES5**

`includes` - will return `true` if the `subStr` is in the `str`.

`indexOf` - will return `-1` if no match found, and a if the `subStr` was found, will return the `index`, from where the `subStr` starts.

**Examples**

```js
var str = "Hello World +1 new test Good Morning";
var subStr = "+1 new test";

console.log(str.includes(subStr)); // ES6

console.log(str.indexOf(subStr) !== -1); // ES5
```

Comment: @Rajesh yes of course

Comment: This is not a duplicate question @Rajesh. My question is to match exact phrase. indexOf, contains, search etc. were not answering my questions

Comment: @aks **exact substring inside a string** what do you mean by this then? Also code shared is also pointing to it. If you think its not duplicate, please share both correct case and incorrect case. That would clarify your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `includes`

```js
var str = "Hello World +1 new test Good Morning";
var subStr = "+1 new test";

console.log(str.includes(subStr));     // ECMAScript 6

console.log(str.includes("anything")); // ECMAScript 6
```

Comment: This seems to be a very basic question. Should you not mark it as duplicate instead?

Comment: @Rajesh sure :)

Answer (score 1):

`+` is a RegEx token, meaning to match one or more of the preceding token.

You need to escape it to make the RegEx engine treat it literally:

```
\+1 new test
```

Although as others have mentioned, you should look at string manipulation rather than RegEx in this case.

Comment: This seems to be a very basic question. Should you not mark it as duplicate instead?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `regex` here.

```
str.indexOf(subStr) >=0
```

This will return true if substring found

Comment: This seems to be a very basic question. Should you not mark it as duplicate instead?

Comment: @Rajesh, yes you are right

Comment: var str = "Hello World";
var subStr = "Hell";
then, str.indexOf(subStr) returns 0;
if var subStr = "Hello"; then too str.indexOf(subStr) returns 0.

Comment: I was looking for a solution that matches entire Substring. IndexOf is not serving that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Since '+' sign is valid regex we will need to escape it using a \ like "\+ ". Here is the working example.

```js
var str = "Hello World +1 new test Good Morning";
var subStr = "\+1 new test"
var bol = str.indexOf(subStr) > -1;
console.log(bol);
```

Comment: Please add explanation. Just putting working code is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

The includes() method determines whether a string contains the characters of a specified string.
This method returns true if the string contains the characters, and false if not.
Note: The includes() method is case sensitive.

Example :

```
var str = "Hello +1 world, welcome to the universe.";
var subStr = str.includes("+1 world");
```

Where subStr  is equal to true